# Madden 11 (Wii) Feature List

Tags: nintendo-wii, madden-11

I'm looking for a list of features for Madden 11 for the Wii.  I understand there will be a franchise mode?  Does the franchise mode incorporate all of the usual features of franchise mode (free agency, draft, trading, etc.) or is it watered down?  Will there be superstar mode or something similar?

I understand that there is an arcade type mode for playing with friends that aren't as experienced but has there been any information released about the 'normal' mode?

Answer (score 1):

Not really into the whole Madden scene, but this [promo page](http://maddennfl.easports.com/features.action?platform=wii) from the game's own site seems to answer some of your question.

From what I gather they changed the franchise mode (they refer to it as "redefined"), but I couldn't judge the change as I am unfamiliar with the series.